# What do do with a question relating to a problem fixed on restart?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on StackOverflow relating to a problem I had with my IDE flagging up errors. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27111381/where-is-system-move-in-delphi-xe2).

The root cause of the problem is a mystery but it turns out that the problem went away after a restart. I edited the question to reflect this but I'm unsure what the accepted practice is in this situation. On the basis that people may experience similar problems I left the question open so that if someone searches for a similar problem they will find it and it may be of some use. Should I add a `'Try a restart'` answer? Should I close the question? Or should I leave it open as is with the edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a close reason specifically to state:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

That's exactly the case here.