# Dealing with answers recommending an update or restart

Tags: discussion, review-queues

When reviewing (late) answers in the queue, recently a few answers came up, that I was struggling with. The were along the line like:

- restarting the tool helped
- rebooting the computer removed the issue
- updating the software (x to version yy.zzz) fixed it for me

---

**Why is that a problem?**

IMO it's just common sense to restart something or to look for an update. Even if those answers could be helpful, it's far away from a quality answer.

> "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"  -every IT-Support everywhere

I see this as a waste of peoples time. It's not much, but still people have to read these one sentence answers and have to scroll further. (It's the same with "Hello" "Please help - urgent" and "thank you" in a post)

---

**Where I think it's ok:**

IMO an update-recommendation is reasonable, when there is a suitable bugreport (linked) for the currently used version. In this case, I would accept the answer as helpful.

---

Currently, I skip most of the answers in the queue and sometimes downvote some of the restart-recommendations. But I don't want to foreward this work forever and also downvoting answers kind of hurts my reputation. There has to be a better way.

How would you review those kind of answers?

Comment: Downvote and move on. Depending on the answer a flag might work, but that depends a lot on many of the post circumstances. Downvoting is safe and useful.

Comment: Can you provide some examples ?

Comment: Such answers are reasonable. Not everyone thinks to update or restart an application when am error occurs.

Comment: Related: [Problem is not reproducible anymore -- should I delete my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298891) [What do do with a question relating to a problem fixed on restart?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277774) [How much longer can one reproduce?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289151)

Comment: Not everyone will reflexively try to restart when they run into an issue. If there's a common issue X for which the solution which usually works is to restart, I think a SO answer saying to do so would be perfectly reasonable. (An explanation would help too, but having the answer at all is better than the alternative)

Comment: Do you have explicit examples of where the answer was given and that it was poor?  While I don't disagree with the sentiment of, "this is probably an okay response", I'd like to see the questions.  If the questions  beg for this kind of response, are the *questions* on-topic?

Comment: Converting the answer to a comment can be an option. (moderators can convert answers into comments)

Comment: FWIW I have been helped by an answer here which was essentially "close Visual Studio and reopen it". I'd have never thought of that, I figured I had made a mistake in a project property, so that answer was *very* helpful

Comment: [Restarting Android Studio](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9si4tb/how_many_times_do_you_have_to_invalidate_cache/) is almost a habit for Android developers ;)

Comment: *"IMO it's just common sense to restart something or to look for an update"* take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702699/how-can-i-resolve-the-table-dbo-foo-already-exists-error-when-the-table-doe), restarting wasn't an obvious option for a lot of people with that issue :)

Comment: At least for me, "updating the software (x to version yy.zzz) fixed it for me" does not quite fit with the other two points. Updating some dependency can, depending on the project, take coordination with teams around the globe, significant testing and potentially months before it reaches the customer. So knowing what exactly I'm supposed to update from the stack of dependencies can be quite useful. I agree with the general sentiment and Cody's answer though.

Answer (score 12):

**The "official" line is: yes, these are answers.**

They are legitimate attempts to answer the question, and therefore not eligible for "not an answer" flags. When reviewing such answers, edit if you can improve the content and/or presentation, vote if you feel so moved, and then indicate you're done.

I say "official" because that's the rule that will never steer you wrong. It's consistent with [everything you read on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer); it's consistent with [the apples guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and [its redux](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). Excerpted from the official Meta Stack Overflow FAQ for usage of the "not an answer" flag:

> #### What NOT To Flag
>
> **Any post that attempts to answer the question—however badly—is still an answer**! Do not use the "not an answer" flag
>   for *wrong* answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness
>   of answers.
>
> You can downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers
>   and not useful, but they are *still answers*, so you should not flag
>   them.

So, realize that by flagging these as "not an answer", you would be flying in the face of official guidance and therefore are risking having your flag(s) declined.

---

That said, I have a *slightly* more nuanced take on this. You have to ask yourself the following question:

> Would this answer ever be useful to someone? Is having this visible on the site actually making the Internet a better place?

I mean *really* ask yourself that. Don't just trigger on some superficial issues with the post (like its length), or try to blindly follow some rule. Use your brain to analyze the quality of the answer, its relevance to the question, and its usefulness.

I will delete answers like this when they are *extremely* low effort and nigh-irrelevant to the problem at hand. As you say here, you could almost literally post "did you try restarting?" as an answer to every question on Stack Overflow (and Super User, and Server Fault, and Ask Different, and…). Or a variation, like "please try reinstalling Visual Studio". In 90% of cases, these are pure noise.

**If it looks like they're just coming straight outta left field—in other words, if they're just wild guesses that could be posted to every question on this site irrespective of context, and they're not accompanied with an explanation of *why* that was causing the problem and why that fixes it—then they're not answers.** They're nothing more than wild guesses, and we are under no obligation to keep them around. In fact, we're under an obligation *not* to keep them around, because they are just junking up the place.

Note that I'm not saying *wrong* answers should necessarily be deleted. There's a big difference between a good guess that just happened to be incorrect in a particular situation and a wild guess that was *expectedly* incorrect or irrelevant.

So, it's your choice. If you have [delete-vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), then there's no real choice: use them. If not, and you're the gambling type, you can try flagging it for deletion. I won't decline a VLQ or NAA flag on answers like this, but realize that some moderators will. I'm not going to let a technicality be a justification for keeping a useless, low-quality answer on the site. But I'm also not going to upvote a Meta question complaining about your flag getting declined when it does, in fact, get declined by a moderator who follows the official guidance.

The safe choice, as ever, is "Skip". Let a 20k+ reviewer handle it. Downvoting is also never the wrong choice.

Answer (score -6):

Sometimes it is indeed related to version differences, it has definitely happened for me. But if an answer is a question asking if you've turned it off and on again, it's perfectly ok to flag as "Not an Answer".

Now, there may be a rare case where this is a legit answer, but in 8 years, I haven't seen it. Answers require detail, so if the answer is in between flag and downvote, just remember it's not a death sentence to be wrong. That being said, if unsure, I downvote it and ask somebody else if they feel it's flag worthy.

Comment: This makes no sense. If turning it off and back on again is the solution to the problem then it is definitely an answer. As such the suggestion to turn it off and back on again is an attempt to answer the question, therefore such an answer categorically should not be flagged as Not an Answer, nor would such an answer qualify as having severe content or formatting problems. If you feel such answers are not useful, you should downvote them, but i see nothing warranting a flag of any sort.

Comment: @TinyGiant there's definitely a lot of context that would create that scenario, but I would agree that most scenarios of that nature are pretty easy to decipher or just walk away from