# What is the next step for a user who continuously downvotes me and is being rude to me?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I noticed that a user with who we had a disagreement in the past about *when* to downvote and when to leave a comment in an answer was downvoting me serially (but not e.g. 5 downvotes in 1 min, so the reversal script didn't reverse the votes) without a reason and sometimes in accepted answers where I was sure that they were correct (noticed downvotes in my answers because of his reputation).

Recently, he has been quite rude to me, not admitting his mistakes, rolling back my edits to his answers, supporting strange ideas about the site and posting useless comments directed at me.

My question is **not** how to report this, but what should I do as I have contacted **2** times with the SE team in https://stackoverflow.com/contact and 1 time with moderators raising a custom mod flag in one of my posts, the flag was marked helpful.

So, in all of the cases, user undid his votes, I am not sure if he was warned, but even if he was, he is continuing to do it when I am active at answering.

What is something else I should do? Continuing flagging? I recently flagged one of my questions because they were serially downvotes, mod declined the flag saying that the reversal script will reverse the votes and after the reverse **seems** like the user downvoted one of my best questions and I am afraid more downvotes will come in the future. Contacting again the team? They don't usually respond immediately, so I don't think this will help much.

Comment: Did you get a reply after reporting it to the SE team? They might just not have gotten to handling it yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate/related: [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: Independtly of the how serial voting is never right, if you have problems with a specific user, it may be better to try to steer clear from them instead of further engaging with them. This line: _"not admitting his mistakes, rolling back my edits to his answers, supporting strange ideas about the site and posting useless comments directed at me"_ makes it seem like you may be over-engaging with a toxic user. Just disengage and let someone else deal with them. Just to preserve your own sanity.

Comment: When did you contact them? [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284948/how-long-should-i-wait-for-contact-support-to-respond) appeared to wait about 3 weeks. Patience is a virtue. Additionally the downvotes I can see that look even remotely like serial dv are from 20th March, all 3 of which *were* reversed the next day...

Comment: Elected moderators can't see the contents of what you asked the SE team about. However, I can see that your very latest report to the SE team was just this  Monday... give 'em a bit more time to respond one way or t'other. I also don't see your concern with the mod flag - it was handled accordingly.

Comment: @ErikA they first replied with a bunch of reasons someone would downvote and that I shouldn't take that personally, that was however on Mar 11, when the user hadn't started being rude at me.

Comment: @smileycreations15 this is ***not*** **about serial voting**, the user is also being rude and except that my question is not what I should do, but what should I do after what is mentioned in the post you linked which I have read before.

Comment: @yivi you are right, again! I will start just ignore them and move on. I really have better things to do instead of hearing them shouting all the time. However, there are sometimes where I feel infected and have to react somehow, I already have flagged one of their comments unfriendly and the flag was marked helpful; note also that downvotes hurt a bit - in my score tag.

Comment: @NickA as mentioned 2 times > the first one on Feb 9, got response on 12 Feb, second on 11 Mar and oh, wait! These are 3 times! The third was on Mar 26, in the last 2 I didn't get any response. I seem to have mis-rephrased voting. It is not exactly serial, just he downvotes my post; he seems that he took his lesson on Mar 20 and I am afraid he will avoid the serial voting and go by downvoting my questions and answers one by one or even something like this.

Comment: @double-beep You mentioned how many not when ;) and you haven't really any reason to be worried, you got some downvotes, it got reversed, it's been 2 weeks and not again happened since, you're dwelling on something that they've almost certainly forgotten about, I wouldn't think anything of it :)

Comment: @JonClements my ticket on Apr 1 isn't related about this issue, but about a [review ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382267) (so completely unrelated), however, my last ticket about this was on Mar 26 as mentioned and I have given them about 1 week (it also included that the user is being rude to me).

Comment: @NickA as mentioned, downvotes aren't the only problem, they may have been temporarily paused, but that's just because I was active at moderating Stack Overflow rather than answering questions.

Comment: So, now someone downvoted my other questions; I don't know if it is from Meta, but I wish it can stop.

Comment: @double-beep If you are nearly sure, flag always. Although the mods can't see directly, who did it, they have various means to investigate such a case, and not even your "fan" can know, exactly what. Maybe he commits some mistake. You are not allowed to know anything from the details and from the results. *If you are not very sure, let it as it is.* If you are very sure, always flag. Needless to say, you shouldn't ever do the same, regardless the circumstances!

Comment: @double-beep Another important thing: the "fan" wants to deter you from your meta activities, so this is the last what you should do. Never allow coercion, continue your meta activities as if nothing had happened. Btw, I am one of the least liked avid MSO users, but revenge downs happen rarely to me. It is not so big problem, it only annoys. (Particularly some of my good, but deeply downvoted questions.)

Answer (score -18):

If he says something correctly, then thank him the improvement.

If he says something wrongly, then politely refuse and try to disprove him with independent, third-party references. Again, and again. After he burns down himself multiple times, he will likely stop.

If he says correct things, then he tries to attack you, but in facts helps you (to improve your posts). In this case, his real intent does not matter, you can be thankful for him ;-)

If he insults, flag it.

If you are sure or nearly sure that he did a revenge downvote, flag.

Note, the mods have no way to say you, what they did against this user. It already happened to me (not on the SO), that I've experienced multiple main site revenge downs for some of my meta activity. I flagged it. The flag was declined with some meaningless reasoning ("mods can't see votes, so we can't handle your problem", or so). Some days later I've seen one of our young members, who represented an opposing opinion than mine, but we had no conflicts and nearly no interaction, being in suspension for "voting irregularities".

Of course I have no way to know, if there were any connection between the events.

The important thing is: *probably not I was the only one who got his wonderful actions*. The mods see not only your flags, they see also the flags of the others! From that, they have a general impression, what is going on the site. To make this impression enough well detailed, you need to help them.

If you aren't doing something which is very well visible (for example, posting continuously disliked posts, like my this answer, to the meta site), then he won't be able to keep this too long.

Be careful if his rep is far higher than yours. Having a high rep roughly means that the system considers him more important than you. No, it doesn't mean that they would have a free hand, and they still have to keep the rules.

Comment: Rules of thumb: Don't speak to troll. And don't reply, again and again, in order to trigger insult.  they "win" the second you start responding knowing what it was. They simply doesn't have the same win condition.

Comment: "Having a high rep roughly means that the system considers him much more important than you." I strongly disagree.

Comment: @xdtTransform "Troll" is a meaningless, crap word. Don't use it on the SE, it is not the Facebook. The real meaning of the world "troll" is: "someone who I dislike and won't shut up". The description of the OP clearly doesn't fall in this category. He is talking about someone following him, insulting him and downvoting him.

Comment: @xdtTransform And I reject and ignore your disagreement, and I consider it as a signature of that you don't know enough well the system, together with the 4 other wonderful "SE experts" who voted it up.

Comment: "I mainly ignore **your** downvotes", as you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzugF.png) screen caps I didn't downvote.
That's exactly why. Our disagrement on this point is strong.
I don't need to explain my point of view I know we won't be able to understand each other. 
I didn't even think of downvoting. I Believe it's ok to disagree.

Comment: @peterh The funny thing with those replies is, I genuinely can't tell if you're trolling

Comment: @xdtTransform Ok, I accept your view. No prob.

Comment: @NickA I am trying to help others on the meta SO. Unfortunately, this help means mainly psychological support against the majority of the community. In my view, it is not a mistake, it is a volunteer help for others. In the view of the majority opinion of the MSO community, it is not.

Comment: I actually think this is a really good answer. I don't understand the downvotes. I suspect it's an English as a second language problem that's causing some misunderstanding.

Comment: @YvetteColomb could you elaborate why a suggestion to replying to a troll until they are giving up or write something flagable is a good idea? Or maybe I don't understand the answer.

Comment: @BDL Could you elaborate what "trolls" are you talking about? I would be so happy if I had no reason to think, that you are one of them. Btw, the "short leash" on which the mods are kept by the SE, doesn't mean that you are free to insult them.

Comment: @peterh: With troll I mean the user op is having a problem with. The one who *"has been quite rude to me, not admitting his mistakes, rolling back my edits to his answers, supporting strange ideas about the site and posting useless comments directed at me"* How did I insult a moderator? Your answer (at least to me) says that one should reply to such a user "Again, and again. After he burns down himself third time, he will likely stop." I don't think that replying to such users at all is a good idea. That's why I asked Yvette why she thinks it is a good idea.

Comment: @BDL Yes, I believe it is a good idea. It doesn't matter, if he doesn't admits his mistakes, because the viewers of the future will see. If he doesn't get an answer, then the viewers of the future might remain in the false belief that he had right. If the critics of this user are good, then he actually helps, even if his intent was to harm.

Comment: @BDL You need to be able to defend your opinion. Simply ignoring such people might create some false belief of some "intellectual/ethical superiority", but only for yourself. Fact is that the viewers of the future will only see a critic what you didn't (couldn't) react.

Comment: @peterh: I would usually tell a user about such situations to walk away. Getting engaged in an argument in the comment section rarely does anything good. Answering once to show your view might be fine, but starting a discussion in the comments is imho inappropriate. It's perfectly fine that you have another opinion on that. I'm still waiting for a reason why you claim that I insulted a moderator. I only asked her to tell me her reasoning why she thinks your answer is a good idea.

Comment: @BDL If you had written these to me, I had considered it as an insult, what I can't flag, because it is formulated CoC-compliantly. Thus, I hadn't reacted it, but I had done what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @BDL I am also thinking that many of the unfair attacks the mods get, are rooting in a collective urge of the site to have more open mod positions on the next election. If is starts to just repeat his statements in an infinite loop, then anybody will see also that, so I think after 1-2 repeat you can leave the context as it is.

Comment: @BDL I don't agree with that. I think the guts of the answer is good, but could do with a rewrite.

Comment: What? Mods can see votes as a percentage of the received votes by user. It is available at `/admin/show-user-votes/{user id}`

Comment: @smileycreations15 I can't see, how does it relate to the discussion or to the post. For the not (yet) deleted content, this information can be get also in the SEDE.